# ABI encode array of structs ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, struct, encoding

In `Ethers.js`, how do I encode an array of structs?

The struct:

```js
struct FacetCut {
   address facetAddress;
   FacetCutAction action; //<--- enum
   bytes4[] functionSelectors;
}
```

Function's signature:

```js
function diamondCut(
   FacetCut[] calldata _diamondCut,
   address _init,
   bytes calldata _calldata
) external override {
   //some code
}
```

Ethers' struct ABI-encoding would be, in this case (if it weren't an array):

```
tuple(address facetAddress, uint8 action, bytes4[] functionSelectors) _diamondCut
```

But this is an array, so how would I represent that? I looked into their docs but couldn't find anything.

I've tried placing the [] all around the tuple encoding, but none has worked out:

```
tuple[](address facetAddress, uint8 action, bytes4[] functionSelectors) _diamondCut
[]tuple(address facetAddress, uint8 action, bytes4[] functionSelectors) _diamondCut
tuple(address facetAddress, uint8 action, bytes4[] functionSelectors)[] _diamondCut
tuple(address facetAddress, uint8 action, bytes4[] functionSelectors) _diamondCut[]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**:

```
tuple(address facetAddress, uint8 action, bytes4[] functionSelectors)[] _diamondCut
```

Had a bug somewhere else